# How to web scrape information from multiple URLs in a dynamic website?

Tags: r, web-crawler, network-analysis

I am trying to scrape data from a UN website to do some network analysis. Each entity/partner will be a node and each SDG will be a link. However, to obtain the .csv that I need, I've been trying to get all the urls for the webcrawling but so far I have not succeded. Then, after that, I need the code to help me get into each project and get the entities and related SDG for each project.

So far, I have tried the following code:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

httr::set_config(httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"))

PARTNERSHIPS <- read_html("https://sdgs.un.org/partnerships/browse?page=0")

PROJECTNAMES <- PARTNERSHIPS %>% html_elements("span a")

PROJECT_URLS <- PARTNERSHIPS %>% 
  html_elements("span a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

PROJECT_NAMES <- PARTNERSHIPS %>%
  html_elements("span a") %>%
  html_text2()

PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS <- data.frame(PROJECT_NAMES,PROJECT_URLS)
```

This gives me the list of the only 18 projects displayed in the web page. Which is as follows:

[URLs List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljAUJ.png)

I tried using "while" and "for" to get the links from the 423 pages but I haven't been able to get more than ten.

What can I do to get all the links and then, get all that info from each url?

Answer (score 1):

You can do with:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

httr::set_config(httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"))

# 423 instead of 1
for (i in 0:1) {
  url <- paste("https://sdgs.un.org/partnerships/browse?page=",i, sep = "")
  PARTNERSHIPS <- read_html(url)
  
  PROJECTNAMES <- PARTNERSHIPS %>% html_elements("span a")
  
  PROJECT_URLS <- PARTNERSHIPS %>% 
    html_elements("span a") %>%
    html_attr("href")
  
  PROJECT_NAMES <- PARTNERSHIPS %>%
    html_elements("span a") %>%
    html_text2()
  
  for (j in 1:((length(PARTNERSHIPS |> html_elements("div.field-content")))/2)) {
    if(j == 1)
      GOALS <- PARTNERSHIPS %>%
        html_elements("div.field-content") %>%
        .[[2*j-1]] %>%
        html_elements("div.layout.layout--onecol") %>%
        html_elements("div.layout__region.layout__region--content") %>%
        html_elements("div.goals-lists") %>%
        html_elements("a") %>%
        html_text2() %>%
        paste(collapse = ",")
    else
      GOALS <- c(GOALS,
                 PARTNERSHIPS %>%
                   html_elements("div.field-content") %>%
                   .[[2*j-1]] %>%
                   html_elements("div.layout.layout--onecol") %>%
                   html_elements("div.layout__region.layout__region--content") %>%
                   html_elements("div.goals-lists") %>%
                   html_elements("a") %>%
                   html_text2() %>%
                   paste(collapse = ","))
  }
  
  if (i == 0) PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS <- data.frame(PROJECT_NAMES,PROJECT_URLS,GOALS)
  else PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS <- rbind.data.frame(PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS,
                                                data.frame(PROJECT_NAMES,PROJECT_URLS,GOALS))
}

nrow(PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS)

#> [1] 36
```

I just read 2 first pages of this website and for each page there's 18 project, and for 2 pages there are 36 observations for dataframe.

Comment: I ran with **423** instead of **9** and `nrow(PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS)` is **7618** now.

Comment: Also, there are some duplicates in this dataframe, run `which(duplicated(PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS) == T)` to know row numbers of duplicates or use `PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS <- unique(PARTNERSHIP_ANALYSIS)` to have only unique observations

Comment: I find a method for SDG's but need to improvements. I'll be back.